# Given a username and password, how do you impersonate that user elevated?

Tags: c#, impersonation, elevated-privileges

In Windows Vista and later, `LogonUser` returns a non-privileged token, even if the user provided is an administrator. Thus, when you impersonate using that token, you are non-elevated. Given a correct username and password for an administrator user, how do you run code that has elevated privileges for that administrator?

Comment: Are you wanting to impersonate an AD account, or a local account?

Comment: Active Directory, primarily - though if it works for local as well that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are writing a Windows service, using `LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE` instead of `LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE` or `LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS` will result in a privileged token, as long as the user you want to impersonate has 'log on as a service' permissions.

This doesn't provide a general solution (it won't work if you're writing a user-facing application), but is sufficient to solve the specific problem I had.

Answer (score 1):

I just worked with [this 
example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chf6fbt4.aspx.), It actually works fine.
I guess if you want to run code in this context you'll have to set the current thread principal by:

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());
```